# Scheduler for node that works for >25 days.

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I need a job scheduler for a web app made in node. 
I have looked at both node-cron and node-scheduler, but booth seems to be built on top of Node's `setTimeout()` function. The problem with this is that `setTimeout()` has a max timeout of roughly 25 days, as stated here:
http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_settimeout_cb_ms

If I need scheduling, lets say every third month... how do I solve this?

Comment: What about the system cron? You can use it.

Comment: You could try [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule), a cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node. Another library worth trying is [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), a light-weight job scheduling library for Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line in `node-cron`: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/blob/master/lib/cron.js#L382

It basically indicates that node-cron handles the `setTimeout()` overflow and will split the larger timespan in multiple smaller ones. You should be able to use it safely.

In fact, this functionality [is covered by node-cron's unit](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/blob/master/tests/test-cron.js#L320) tests as well. If the value supplied to the `setTimeout()` is greater than the maximum, it will fire immediately. This unit tests checks whether, after supplying the huge value (1000 months), the test will not fire in the 250 ms time window.

```
'test long wait should not fire immediately': function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    var count = 0;
    var d = new Date().getTime() + 31 * 86400 * 1000;
    var job = cron.job(new Date(d), function() {
      assert.ok(false);
    });
    job.start();
    setTimeout(function() {
      job.stop();
      assert.ok(true);
      assert.done();
    }, 250);
},
```

Comment: Do you know if this still working after the app has been restarded?

Comment: @Mr.Birkoff - if you mean after the node process has been killed and started again - in that case, of course, the setTimeout won't be preserved.

Comment: yes..., wouldn't be better for him set a system cron? Since 25 days is long period? What you think?

Comment: @RodrigoNascimento - I don't know what OP is going to do with such a long interval. Hard to tell whether system cron is a better fit.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to solve this problem in the wrong way. Basicly what I want is to send out invoices to clients of a web app every quarter, thas is four set dates every year. This should be done automatically. 

If this is complicated I could just scrap this whole function and just add a button in my "superadmin" view that sends these invoices... 

BUT i will still need scheduling, because the app is a kind of queue where clients could set up reminders... and they will definitely be "longer" than 25 days from time to time.

Comment: @AndersÖstman in that case system cron seems to be a better fit. Why? 1) it's stable, widely used 2) it will survive your app crashes and restarts 3) it's automatically started when server boots, so it will survive server crash & reboot. You should use the following cron rule: `0 0 1 */3 * node /send-invoices.js` - this will send invoices at midnight, first day of every third month. See `man 5 crontab` for details.

Comment: Yes, But when the application is running more reminder will be created... Is it easy to let my application communicate with the system cron to insert more events?

Comment: @AndersÖstman The system cron will only execute the command "node send-invoices.js" All the logic and to whom/how to send will be done inside your send-invoices.js.

Answer (score 1):

[agenda](http://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) will also handle your needs. It stores schedule job times in a database and then will poll the database on a given interval (`agenda.processEvery`) looking for jobs that need to be done.

Full disclosure, I am the author of agenda.

Comment: I recently wrote a blog comment about agenda, project setup and project structure goo.gl/5sCNBM